# How to put these outputs into 9 by 9 array using Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

sorry if this is a basic question. I am just starting with python and programming.

I want the output from iteration in a 9 by 9 array. For now I just get the output in one column.

```
for q in range(11,20,1): 
    for x in range(11,20,1):
        if q <= x: 
            V = 3.5*q ‐ 1.5 * x
        elif q > x: 
            V = 3.5*x ‐ 1.5*x
print(V)
```

Try doing this but I get error: **IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9**

```
import numpy as np
V = np.zeros((9,9))

for q in range(11,20,):
    for x in range(11,20):
        if q <= x:
            V[q][x] = 3.5*q - 1.5*x
        elif q > x:
            V[q][x] = 3.5*x - 1.5*x
print(V)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is exactly what the error says: you are trying to access index 11 in a an array of size 9 (by 9).

`for q in range(11,20):` is iterating over `q = 11, 12, 13,..., 19`. 
Then `V[q][x]` is trying to access element with indexes `q` and `x` in `V`. But `V` is of size 9x9 which means the only elements you can access are `[0,0], [0,1], ..., [0,8], [1,0], ..., [8,8]` hence the error: you are trying to acess an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: Than you for your reply.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The numbers I want for q and x are from (11....19). 9 element for each, that's why I created the 9X9 size array.  Please any idea on how to go about this.